# XML File to Java Object at deployment in Spring Boot and access from JSP page?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot (2.7.2) web application deployed as a .war file on Tomcat. I am using JSP for templating and Java Configuration.

When the application starts up I would like it to read the XML file which is located in the WEB-INF directory and create a Java Object based on that file. That POJO should be accessible from more than one JSP page.

Comment: This is a pretty standard use for a servlet though there are certainly other ways of handling it.  Is this data read-only or do you need to re-write the XML?  Are you running into issues implementing it?

Comment: @stdunbar the xml data is read only. I have the xml file and classes, and I'm able to unmarshall the xml using JAXB. I'm not that familiar with all of Spring's mechanisms and lifecycle as I need to be and I'm not finding the right search terms that bring how to do it with Java Configuration. Based on other ways Spring handles XML I'm guessing there's a better way to do this. I'm also not sure how to put the object in application scope in a way that's accessible from jsp such as ${myXmlObject}